# MonoTouch: Cannot add web reference to my iPad project?

Tags: web-services, xamarin.ios

I have a (WCF) web service setup and it looks everything works fine. However, when I try to add the wsdl file to my iPad project in MonoTouch, it gave me an error "schema type 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...' has not been imported yet. Import it first." What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you following [this](http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF) guide?

You have to use SlSvcUtil.exe to generate some cs files to put in your project.  I don't think you can add a WSDL file to your project and make it work somehow.

Using SlSvcUtil.exe worked great for us, in combination with a WCF service built with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. As I already posted, I found a solution to my problem. Yes, IT IS POSSIBLE to add a web referece in MonoTouch through a WSDL file (which was generated in VS 2008 WCF project in my case).

Comment: I did not realize the "Add Web Reference" dialog existed in MonoDevelop, but yeah it's definitely there.  You have to right-click on the project, but it doesn't show up if you right-click on the References folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ACCIDENTALLY found a solution for my problem. In MonoTouch Add Web Reference dialog, there is a combobox for Framework which contains two options: Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and .NET 2.0 Web Services. The WCF is selected by default. However, when I accidently selected the .NET 2.0 Web Services, it works. I don't know if this is a defect in MonoDevelop or something else.

Comment: No it is not a defect.  Your web service is obviously a .Net 2.0 web service and not WCF.

Comment: @Jonathan, my web service was created by following the "WCF Screencast - Hosting WCF Services in IIS" [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX8quq7MoeI) from pluralsight in youtube. Basically, i used Visual Studio 2008 template "WCF Service Library" to create the project and then add a new web site using WCF Service, and published to IIS server. So, how can you be sure my service is not WCF?

Comment: Just to give another update on this issue...The web reference generated this way has some problems: I can get the object from the server without problem, but some of the properties cannot be pushed back to server - initially I had problem with int type, but later I also run into similar problem for string type. I have no idea why. I'm guessing this might be related to the fact that my wsdl is generated in WCF, but imported as .NET 2.0 Web services.